# Pure Twig & Bootstrap 3, How to force twig to load necessary bootstrap css & js files?

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, twig

Q: How to force twig to load necessary bootstrap css & js files?
On ***stackoverflow*** I didn't find similar question.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LAMP server. Then I install only twig (without symfony)

> cd /var/www/html/twig
>
> composer require twig/twig

Installed version was 2.4.4. In twig directory I downloaded bootstrap 3.0.0

> wget https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/archive/v3.0.0.zip

I unpacked it and than I create directory *template* in twig directory

> mkdir /var/www/html/template

In that directory I created index.html file which is the copy of bootstrap/example/theme/index.html. With some changes in that file, when you go with url

> http://localhost/twig/template/index.html

file works perfectly.
After that I created the index.php file in twig directory

> nano /var/www/html/index.php

```
<?php
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('./template');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);

echo $twig->render('index.html', array('name' => 'Fabien'));
```

Now, when you go with url

> http://localhost/twig

file doesn't load perfectly index.html file from *template* directory (as if css and js files were not included).

What should I do to force twig to load bootstrap example theme/index.html file normally (I mean on correct way)?

Comment: Your need to fix the relative paths to the css/js, their probably set at `./css/` but your need `./template/css` etc

Comment: bootstrap directory is one step out from template directory. I mean bootstrap and template directory are both on same level in twig directory.

Comment: Twig wont fix the paths which are hardcoded in your html file, your need to move the asset files. `Twig_Loader_Filesystem('./template');` is simply to tell twig where your html files are. when rendered out the path wont change, if you need that functionality your need to add another lib like webpack and change the path to assets accordingly.

Comment: Thank's for very quick response. You are right. I tried it and it works. I put css & js files in template directory and it works. Thank's again.